# Looking for an entry level discussion on convex analysis

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

I have been studying for a qualifier and every so often I come across questions such as:

Let $f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex functions and suppose that $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists at all $x \in [a,b]$ and is continuous on $[a,b].$  Prove that $f_n \to f$ uniformly. (Any help would be appreciated)

OR

[Showing that $f$ is convex given that $(\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)) \cdot (x-y) \geq c(x-y)\cdot(x-y), \;\;\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758802/showing-that-f-is-convex-given-that-nabla-fx-nabla-fy-cdot-x-y)

The books I have do not contain such topics, does anyone know a good reference?  A brief introduction would be ideal, seeing as I would just like to get the flavor of the proofs down before the test, and any essential techniques used.  Thanks in advance.